# Flatlist and data-mapping didn't show data

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I tried to map my data using array.prototype.map() but the data merges into one line, and I tried using flatlist as alternative but it doesn't show anything..... Can someone help me?

```
const array = [
    {name: 'Almer', id: 1},
    {name: 'Donat', id: 2},
    {name: 'Ardi', id: 3},
  ];
```

above is the data

```
 {array.map((e) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{e.name}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      })}
```

Any Help or reference will save my day! Thank You

Comment: That's because that is how `<Text>` works: [Reference](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text)

Comment: Any idea how to fix this?..

Comment: Really? Did you click the link, read the text and view the sample code provided? You should close this question and read the documentation a bit more closely.

Comment: Oh sorry.. and thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Tried with no error:

[image]

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, SafeAreaView, View, FlatList } from "react-native";


const array = [
  { name: 'Almer', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Donat', id: 2 },
  { name: 'Ardi', id: 3 },
];

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>--- array with map ---</Text>
      {array.map((e) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{e.name}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      })}
      <Text>--- FlatList --- </Text>
      <FlatList
        data={array}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
};

export default Test;
```

And snack for furthur changes: [Expo example](https://snack.expo.io/hs_--ZDdd)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know it should behave like that.. but check this out https://ibb.co/SPKRknS

Comment: @user14593851 unless you provide us more lines of your code, i'm pretty sure that i could not figure which leads to the poor behaviour you caught...

Comment: Sorry for that.. but I got no more code to show since that's all the code related to this issue.. but I appreciate all of the answers and help coming in!